# How can pgrep detect only system-level shutdown not any command with the word shutdown in it?

Tags: bash, shutdown

I'm trying to use pgrep shutdown in a linux bash script to detect only the system-level shutdown command, but it's also detecting my scripts whose names have the word shutdown in them. Rather than having to rename my scripts and modifying the scripts that use them to avoid the word shutdown, how can I tell pgrep to detect only the system-level shutdown command ? Everything runs as root, so testing for root does not help. And, when I do a system-level shutdown, I give it a wall message so there's time-varying text attached to the shutdown command.

Comment: Please post examples of the shutdown command and the script names

Comment: `pgrep shutdown in a linux bash script to detect only the system-level shutdown` But why are you using that tool to do that? Run your script on shutdown, install a hook to notify your system that it is being shutdown-ed. Why would you use `pgrep` for that? You want to detect a shutdown or _only_ detect literally the executable `shutdown` being run?

Comment: I want to detect ONLY that the executable shutdown command is running, not just something whose name has the word shutdown in it. I was under the impression that pgrep is very choosy in what it detects, but I discovered this is not true -- it also detects ANYTHING that is running with the word shutdown in it, and I have a number of them to shut down various pieces of hardware such as a modem. I'm rewriting code to do pgrep shutdown and if it matches, to then do ps -Af | grep shutdown | grep -v ".sh" to exclude my scripts, but this takes a lot of execution time on a slow or busy processor.

Comment: The fundamental problem is how to detect when a particular command or script is running. My scripts have long, descriptive names. This is a battery-powered IoT device in the field, not a computer in the office. When power runs low, I shut the system down. Some things take many seconds to stop cleanly, so I give them a warning not to start something, and to exit ASAP. I use a shutdown with 5 minutes, so if they detect it, they can exit cleanly. I also shut some devices, such as a modem, down briefly some times -- not the same as shutting down the system.